# Regular expression on omni form field

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a form field that has one input field: it can be either a username or an email address.

For the username, any combination of numbers and letters will work:

```
johndoe101_username
```

However, an email in this same exact field also works:

```
johndoe@example.com
```

I am having trouble finding a regular expression accepts these two conditions in one. Basically, if the username contains an "@" symbol, then it needs to be a valid email address.

I tried using

```
/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
```

But that rules out if someone has just a username and not an email address.

Is this possible to do? I know suggestions will be to just use two separate input fields, but the design calls for only one.

Comment: add `|\w+` in your regex will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex are actually matching emails but not usernames. Your username pattern are the same for `\w` which accepts letters, numbers and _.

So, if you want an email or usernames, use a `|` (or) operator:

`^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$|^\w{4,10}$`

`+` operator stands for **one to unlimited** number os characters, if, for example, your username must have at least 4 chars and no more than 10, you can use `|\w{4,10}` instead.